# Advanced HTTP/2 proxy for load balancing of distributed scraping solution

Tags: http, proxy, load-balancing, screen-scraping

I have built a distributed HTTP scraper solution that uses different "exit addresses" addresses by design in order to balance the network load.

The solution supports IPv4, IPv6 and HTTP proxy to route the traffic.

Each processor was responsible to define the most efficient route to balance the traffic and it was temporarily implemented manually for prototyping. Currently, the solution grows and with the number of processors as the complexity of the load balancing task get higher, that's why I need a way to create a component dedicated to it.

I did some rather extensive research, but seem to have failed in finding a solution for load balancing traffic between IPv6, IPv4 (thousands of local addresses) and public HTTP proxies. The solution needs to support weights, app-level response checks and cool-down periods.

Does anyone know a solution that already solves this problem? Before I start developing a custom one.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you search for `load balancing proxy` you'll discover the `Cache Array Routing Protocol` (`CARP`). This `CARP` might not be what you're searching for and there exists servers only for the proxy-cache what I never knew till now.
Nevertheless those servers have own `load balancers` too, and perhaps that's a detail where it's worth it to search more.

I found a presentation mentioning `CARP` as outstanding solution too: https://cs.nyu.edu/artg/internet/Spring2004/lectures/lec_8b.pdf

Example: for proxy-arrays in `Netra Proxy Cache Server`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-3512-10/6j3bg665f/index.html

Also there exist several concepts for load-balancing (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1020943021842):

```
The three proposed methods can broadly be divided into centralized and decentralized
approaches. The centralized history (CH) method makes use of the transfer rate of each
request to decide which proxy can provide the fastest turnaround time for the next job.
The route transfer pattern (RTP) method learns from the past history to build a virtual
map of traffic flow conditions of the major routes on the Internet at different times of the
day. The map information is then used to predict the best path for a request at a particular time of the day. The two methods require a central executive to collate information
and route requests to proxies. Experimental results show that self-organization can be
achieved (Tsui et al., 2001). The drawback of the centralized approach is that a bottleneck and a single point of failure is created by the central executive. The decentralized
approach—the decentralized history (DH) method—attempts to overcome this problem
by removing the central executive and put a decision maker in every proxy (Kaiser et al.,
2000b) regarding whether it should fetch a requested object or forward the request to another
proxy.
```

As you use public proxy-servers probably you won't use `decentralized history (DH)` but `centralized history (CH)` OR the `route transfer pattern (RTP)`.

Perhaps it would be even useful to replace your own solution completely, i.e. by this: https://github.blog/2018-08-08-glb-director-open-source-load-balancer/. I've no reason for this special example, it's just random by search results I found.

As I'm not working with proxy-servers this post is just a collection of findings, but perhaps there is a usable detail for you. If not, don't mind - probably you know most or all already and it's never adding anything new for you. Also I never mention any concrete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this project? https://Traefik.io which supports http/2 and tcp load balancing. The project is open source and available on github. It is build using Go. I'm using it now as my reverse proxy with load balancing for almost everything.

I also wrote a small blog post on docker and Go where I showcase the usage of Traefik. That also might help you in your search. https://marcofranssen.nl/docker-tips-and-tricks-for-your-go-projects/

In the traefik code base you might find your answer, or you might decide to utilize traefik to achieve your goal instead of home grown solution.

See here for a nice explanation on the soon to be arriving Traefik 2.0 with TCP support.
https://blog.containo.us/back-to-traefik-2-0-2f9aa17be305

Comment: Thank you, Marco! The product is really great, but I need something on a lower level, as I need to maintain the TCP connections and the outbound IPs to the (usually) same host.

Comment: version 2.0 which is in beta or release candidate does have support for TCP ;)